# Add Disqus number of comments to the posts number of likes

Tags: javascript, css, tumblr, disqus

I would like to add Disqus comments on my Tumblr. It is perfectly doable and they appear as they should.

But what I would like to is to add the number of likes in the posts to the number of Disqus comments the post has received.

The reason is simple. It is not very often that someone leaves me a disqus comment but I receive likes pretty regularly. So if I display them both in one post there is most of the time a "0 Comments" link for it. And this does not look good to me.

So if my post has e.g. 14 likes and then I receive 2 Disqus comments on that post, I would like to have a link that says 16 likes or something like that.

In tumblr the number of Note Counts (likes) is accessible by this condition:

```
{block:NoteCount}
{NoteCount}
{/block:NoteCount}
```

And if you have added Disqus to the blog, the number of comments would be:

```
{block:IfDisqusShortname}
{NoteCount}
{/block:IfDisqusShortname}
```

So is there a way I could add these two numbers i.e. the top `{NoteCount}` and the bottom?